# Is there a reason tags can't be added in the mobile app?

Tags: support, tags, ios-app

I was posting a question in Christianity.SE, and the correct tag - Joshua didn't exist. I have privileges to add tags, but it wouldn't take the new one.

Am I doing something wrong, was this intentional, or is this a bug?

Comment: Same here I couldn't add a tag from iOS